# Script Breaks When Terminal Closes Even When Launched In Background

Tags: mysql, bash, nohup

So I am launching the script below with typical nohup syntax:

```
nohup ./script &
```

A portion of the log output below is what is shown when I have a temporary Internet connection and my terminal windows lock up, forcing me to close them manually. When my problem is resolved I log back in and see this output from the log:

**Log Output: (from results2.log)**

```
--------------
UPDATE table where id between 45759776 and 55759776
--------------

Terminal close -- sending "KILL QUERY 3329619" to server ...
Terminal close -- query aborted.
Bye
--------------
```

**Script Conents:**

```
#!/bin/bash

first=5759776
last=15759776

while [ $first -lt 73843165 ]; do
    mysql -u -p??????? db -vvv -e "UPDATE table where pc.id between $first and $last;" >> results2.log
    ((first=first+10000000))
    ((last=last+10000000))
done
```

So basically two questions:

1. Why did this not run in the background when I closed the terminals?
2. How do I prevent this from occurring in the future?

Comment: what do you want to do with the update ? there is no **set field=xx** in

Comment: The issue isn't with query syntax. I just shorthanded the log text.

Answer (score 1):

Add a trap handler in your script to catch the signals like:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "echo 'trap recieved';" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

first=5759776
last=15759776
....
```

A process can receive signal to inform them over some events. you can send signals with the **kill** command. Also other processes send signals to the process like the parent process. with this command you can catch the signal. if you dont catch them the process will terminate. the only signal is 9 where you cant catch like : kill -9 processid;

Comment: Can you share what this will do?

Comment: @user3299633 - i have add it in my answer